# how to give download permission tobrowserFiled in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

i am able to download a PDF file from default browser.but how  to download pdf file in browserfield?

i hava link in browserField when i click on that link it shoud open a popup screen like default browser. following is my pdf Link

updated.pdf">http://www.vistra.com/media/86238/victor_ho_pdf_for_vistra_website_-_press_release_*updated*.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to OS 4.6 the permission required is PERMISSION_EXTERNAL_CONNECTIONS, for 4.6 and later versions of the OS it is PERMISSION_INTERNET. You can edit the application permission using the application manager, or specificall request the permission from your application using ApplicationPermissionsManager.

Comment: thank you dear i am asking about only browserfield permissions not application permissions dear

Comment: Dear is probably an inappropriate appellation in this context. You asked how to give download permission to a BrowserField, that permission has to be granted to the application executing the download, not to the object containing the method being used. Perhaps you should clarify your question.